# Crop Image at specific location from multiple images

Tags: interface-design, image-editing, information-graphics, crop

I have a multiple images of one app. The original image size is 800x480 pixels. I want to crop a specific part of all images. lets say 50x50 pixels image from original images.

Is there any software or online service which i can use it for.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Are all the crops in every image located in exactly the same position?  If so, you could probably use Photoshop. Record an action, do the crop, stop the recording,  and then apply  the action to a batch of Images using *File > Automate > Batch*. If the crops aren't in the exact same location, you will probably have to do it manually. You could use almost any raster image editor to do manual crops, Photoshop, GIMP, Krita, etc.

Comment: If the crops are in the same position, I would stack the images as layers in one Photoshop document, make the crop and then export the layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using the command line:
ImageMagick could do the job.

Where `magick` is the app from ImageMagick toolbox.

Example:
Input Files are `800x480`

```
magick Input_File_1.png -crop 400x240+0+0 cropped_image_1.png
```

where new size is `400x200` starting at origin, hence offset is `x=0` and `y=0` (can be ommitted)

results in:

| Original | cropped |
| --- | --- |
| [image: input_file_1] | [image: croppend_image_1] |

crop with setting an offset at x,y = (200,120)

```
magick Input_File_1.png -crop 400x240+200+120 cropped_image_1.png
```

where new size is `400x200` and offset is `x=200` and `y=120`

results in:

| Original | cropped |
| --- | --- |
| [image: input_file_1] | [image: cropped_image_2] |

To crop more files use `mogrify` and globbing. **Infiles will be overridden!!!**. Be sure to backup your files before.

```
mogrify -crop 400x240+200+120 Input_File_*.png
```

For your specific use case of having infiles with 800x480 and cropping 50x50, the command would be:

For one file:

```
magick YOUR_INFILE.png -crop 50x50 YOUR_OUTFILE.png
```

For several files, with files i.e.:

```
FILE_1.png
FILE_2.png
FILE_2.png
```

```
mogrify -crop 50x50 FILE_*.png
```

---

get the software at: https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

documentation links:

https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php
https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop
https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

---